# Allow find command to access my files

Tags: terminal, permission

I'm trying to use the `find` command to find a file on my Mac. However, when I used the command I accidentally denied my Mac permission to search my various folders, including documents and photos. How can I reverse this and give the terminal full permissions to search my computer?

The exact command I was using is:
`find / -name "file_name"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two things you should do:

1. Enable full Terminal access by opening System Preferences, selecting the Security Tab, selecting the last tab there, selecting Full Disk Access on the left and adding Terminal.app

[image]

2. Run the command as

   ```
   sudo find / -name "file_name"
   ```

---

Assuming the file you are looking for is within your home folder

```
find ~ -name "file_name"
```

should also work (and is significantly faster).